# How to return the minimum value of multiple columns and return it's header?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

For example, I have the table:

```
Name Week 8am-9am 9am-10am 10am-11am

C1   1    27%     32%      11%
C1   2    4%      29%      95%
C2   3    9%      44%      57%
```

And I'm looking to return the minimum value along with the week and time frame of a specific name, e.g. for Name C1:

```
Name Week 8am-9am
C1   2    4%
```

Comment: Which minimum value, any of the columns?

Comment: The minimum value of the time frames, so in this case; 8am-9am 9am-10am etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check something like that:

```
select name, week, 8am-9am from table t1
where 8am-9am in (selec min(8am-9am) from table t2 group by name having t2.name=t1.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your table design isn't perfect I start with a derived table to `UNION ALL` the different columns into one.

```
select *
from tablename
where (select min(val)
       from
       (
           select "8am-9am" as val from tablename 
           union all
           select "9am-10am" as val from tablename 
           union all
           select "10am-11am" as val from tablename
       )) in ("8am-9am", "9am-10am", "10am-11am")
```